Is it possible to attach Visual Studio Code debugger using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()?
The context involves trying to debug a Fody addin (MsBuild task).
Using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch(); only prompts me with Visual Studio debuggers.

I'm not aware of any UIs that might help you configure this directly. However, you can achieve this by modifying the same registry key mentioned in this MSDN post: Disable Just-In-Time Debugging from the Windows Registry to point to VSCode's debugger instead.
